# How can I set the save location of a file using powershell?

Tags: powershell, printing, save

I am trying to print a PDF as XPS, the script opens the PDF `Print Output As` screen and enters the correct name before sending the `ENTER` command to the window to save the file.

How can I select the address bar to enter the desired path?  Or how can I change the default save path?

EDIT:  Thank you for the feedback.  Here is the script:

```
function print_files($secure_pdf_dir){
    #Retrieves the name for the .xps files
    Get-ChildItem $secure_pdf_dir -Filter *.pdf -Recurse | Foreach-Object {
        #For each .pdf file in that directory, continue
        same_time $_.FullName
    }
}
## The following function keeps checking for a new window called "Save Print Output As"
## When the window shows up, it enters the name of the file and press ENTER
function enter_my_names($xps_dir, $fullname){
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
    while($wshell.AppActivate('Save Print Output As') -ne $true){
        $wshell.AppActivate('Save Print Output As')
    }
    $basename = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($fullname)
    #This is where the name is actually entered
    $wshell.SendKeys($xps_dir\$basename)
    $wshell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
   }

## The following function launches simultaneously a print job on the input file 
## and a function waiting for the print job to show up to name the file
workflow same_time{
    Param(
        $fullname
    )
    parallel{
        Start-Process -FilePath $fullname –Verb Print -PassThru
        enter_my_names $xps_dir $fullname    
    }
}
#MAIN PROGRAM
#Here the script saves your current printer as default
$defprinter = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_Printer Where Default=$true"
#Queries for a XPS printer
$printer = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_Printer Where Name='Microsoft XPS Document Writer'"
#Sets the XPS printer as Default
$printer.SetDefaultPrinter()
#Starts the main job
print_files($secure_pdf_dir)
#Sets the old default printer back as default again
$defprinter.SetDefaultPrinter()
#This is a small delay to be sure everything is completed before closing Adobe Reader. You can probably shorten it a bit
sleep 2
#Finally, close Adobe Reader
Get-Process "acrord32" | Stop-Process
```

It seems that the `$xps_dir` variable is not being passed into the function properly.

Edit:  Error I get when trying to add $xps_dir to the enter_my_names function:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Error : Cannot validate argument on parameter 
'FilePath'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or 
empty, and then try the command again.
At same_time:115 char:115
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], ParameterBindingValidati 
   onException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingValidationEx 
   ception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorCommand
    + PSComputerName        : [localhost]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you got this fully worked out or I misread your post, but I was able to implement some code from your initial post to finish my project [been beating my head against a wall as a non-traditional comp sci person]; so I wanted to share some things I did in hopes of helping you (in the event you're still at that crossroads).

Some points of interest:
-My overall process is a bulk report generator.  A variable amount of .XML stylesheets are sent to IE because a javascript subroutine numbers the reports; to accomplish this I have visual basic doing some database parsing, passing values into custom scripts needed to form the .XML stylesheets, then VB creates PS .ps1 files with the various PS commands needed to create the IE com object.  Finally, VB calls the .ps1 scripts, and the reports are generated by sending the stylesheet to IE, waiting for HTML render, send print command, and close the object.

-While your endgoal is to generate an XPS, mine was to fully render an HTML, then print it with a PDF printer; I assume we have a similar process in that we must engage a dialog box in the intermediate stage (in this case, using sendkeys to interact with it); this is specifically what I'm going to discuss below in hopes of helping out!

So, two points of discussion:

1. First, more of a general observation/query: I don't see where your $xps_dir variable is actually being defined; I mention this because there could be a string-related issue with the values being passed by the $xps_dir.  One way to check your string to make sure its 'pretty' is to pass it to a .txt or something using the OUT-FILE command:

"$xps_dir" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\somefolder\sometext.txt" -Append

The text file itself doesn't need to exist, but the file does...the above command will create the text file.

Also, if you're ok with viewing the powershell prompt, a WRITE-HOST can be used.

Either way, I'm wondering if the final compiled string isn't compiled correctly, so its not recognizing it as a directory.

2. I think what more likely is happening is the SENDKEYS aren't being sent to the correct fields.  For example, by using your code I was [FINALLY] able to set my 'Save As' dialog box as an object and interact with it.  (When using my PDF printer, I get the 'Save As' dialog box).

At first, I tried to send the file name, then send enter.  I assumed this would be fine, because during manual interaction the focus for the 'Save As' dialog box goes to the 'File Name' field; however, after trying:

$wshell.SendKeys($myfilename)
$wshell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")

I realized the SendKeys command was sending the keys to the 'Save in' drop down (or probably the first element of the Save As dialog box).  So, I manually click inside of the 'Save in' field, then tabbed around until I got to 1. 'File Name' (wrote the # of tabs down), and 2. the 'Save' button (wrote # of tabs down).  By adding SendKeys("{TAB}") to correspond with the number of tabs I observed, I was able to successfully enter my name string and close out the print dialog box:

```
$wshell.SendKeys("{TAB}")
    $wshell.SendKeys("{TAB}")
    $wshell.SendKeys("{TAB}")
    $wshell.SendKeys("{TAB}")
    $wshell.SendKeys("{TAB}")
$wshell.SendKeys($myfilename)
    $wshell.SendKeys("{TAB}")
    $wshell.SendKeys("{TAB}")
        $wshell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
```

NOTE: the number of tabs might be different for your dialog box, so I strongly recommend doing a manual run through to count how many tabs get you to the field you want to interact with.

In conclusion, I have one reflection for consideration:

I've used (to much success) VB and PS to use html elements to dynamically enhance my routines.  Since we're able to set the dialog box as a Com object, my next goal will be to try to tap into the respective 'elements', similar to how html elements can be accessed (or more generally, object-oriented language allows).  This way, I might be able to better interact with the dialog box without suffering the drawbacks of SendKeys:

1. Has to run as active process; user cannot engage any other windows else keys might be sent to them;
2. Keys are based on a count; any variation to that count will require the subroutine to be updated/edited, making it not elastic;

Also, I have not done any work regarding error windows, but one I've already noticed is the "your document has the same name blah blah", so just a heads up.

Even though we're doing two different things, here's my final code for this part of my routine in case it helps provide context:

```
#send command to internet explorer application with execWB; 6 for print, 2 for no user prompt on window
while ( $ie.busy ) { Start-Sleep -second 3 }
$ie.execWB(6,2)

#create dialog box object
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
    while($wshell.AppActivate('Save As') -ne $true){ Start-Sleep -second 3 }{
        $wshell.AppActivate('Save As')
}

#create file string from 3 strings: directory,basename returned, file extension
#the return from my output log is: "c:\test_folder\mybasenamestring.PDF"
        $mydirectory = "c:\test_folder\"
            $mybasename = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($fullname)
            $myextension = ".PDF"
            $myfilename = "$mydirectory$mybasename$myextension"

#Using tabs to navigate around the dialog window; send my string to the 'File Name' field, then tab to 'Save' and send enter
#This is where the name is actually entered
    $wshell.SendKeys("{TAB}")
        $wshell.SendKeys("{TAB}")
        $wshell.SendKeys("{TAB}")
        $wshell.SendKeys("{TAB}")
        $wshell.SendKeys("{TAB}")
    $wshell.SendKeys($myfilename)
        $wshell.SendKeys("{TAB}")
        $wshell.SendKeys("{TAB}")
            $wshell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")

#going to add a command to report on the file size of the pdf; the pdf will stay 0kb until its fully generated.  Once fully generated will add the $ie.quit or the kill command here for the $ie object

#this sends a stop process command to kill powershell since I'm running it as a ps1 file and it will remain open otherwise

stop-process -Id $PID
```

Last thing: I observed some weirdness with the capitalization, so I updated the final SendKeys to capitalize the string since I want all caps anyhow:

```
$wshell.SendKeys($myfilename.toupper())
```

Hope this helps!  Thanks for posting; I was finally able to complete my entire process.  As I clean and improve, if I find improvements for this area I'll try to remember to share.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The file dialogue will accept a path in the file name field, so instead of sending the filename `file.pdf` send the full path to the file `C:\folder\folder\file.pdf`

---

**EDIT:**

You can send the folder path like so:

```
$wshell.SendKeys($xps_dir)
$wshell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
$wshell.SendKeys($basename)
$wshell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
```

Comment: Thank you for the input.  I added the code above.  I tried to pass the variable containing the desired directory to the function with no luck so far.  The script works as expected without having the `$xps_dir` variable in the function.

Comment: I've edited my answer, you'll need to send the dir and file name separately.

Comment: Even like that, the info is not being passed from $xps_dir and I get an error.  I added it in my original post.

Comment: My limited knowledge on PS was giving me the trouble.  I wasn't passing the variable through the series of functions being called.  Once I passed it down through each function I was able to use the variable as `$wshell.SendKeys($xps_dir\$basename)`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the variable containing the desired directory ($xps_dir in this case) to each function in the process until it gets to the `enter_my_names` function where it can then be sent to the window with the `$wshell.SendKeys("$xps_dir\$basename")`.

```
function print_files($xps_dir, $secure_pdf_dir){
    #Retrieves the name for the .xps files
    Get-ChildItem $secure_pdf_dir -Filter *.pdf -Recurse | Foreach-Object {
        #For each .pdf file in that directory, continue
        same_time $xps_dir $_.FullName
    }
}
## The following function keeps checking for a new window called "Save Print Output As"
## When the window shows up, it enters the name of the file and press ENTER
function enter_my_names{
    param ($xps_dir, $fullname)
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
    while($wshell.AppActivate('Save Print Output As') -ne $true){
        $wshell.AppActivate('Save Print Output As')
    }
    $basename = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($fullname)
    #This is where the name is actually entered
    $wshell.SendKeys("$xps_dir\$basename")
    $wshell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
}
## The following function launches simultaneously a print job on the input file 
## and a function waiting for the print job to show up to name the file
workflow same_time{
    Param(
        $xps_dir, $fullname
    )
    parallel{
        Start-Process -FilePath $fullname –Verb Print -PassThru
        enter_my_names $xps_dir $fullname
    }
}
#MAIN PROGRAM
#Here the script saves your current printer as default
$defprinter = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_Printer Where Default=$true"
#Queries for a XPS printer
$printer = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_Printer Where Name='Microsoft XPS Document Writer'"
#Sets the XPS printer as Default
$printer.SetDefaultPrinter()
#Starts the main job
print_files $xps_dir $secure_pdf_dir
#Sets the old default printer back as default again
$defprinter.SetDefaultPrinter()
#This is a small delay to be sure everything is completed before closing Adobe Reader. You can probably shorten it a bit
sleep 2
#Finally, close Adobe Reader
Get-Process "acrord32" | Stop-Process
```